# Immutable.JS contact and modifying output

Tags: javascript, object, mocha.js, immutable.js, purely-functional

In immutableJS I'm trying to get the output to .

name: "This field is required. Another error.",
  age: "Only numeric characters are allowed."

```
 const Immutable = require("immutable");
let error = Immutable.fromJS({
  name: ["This field is required", "Another error"],
  age: ["Only numeric characters are allowed"]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**ONELINER**: in-place (answer to [this version of question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53820878/1) - example )

`Object.entries(error).map( x=> error[x[0]] = x[1].join('. ')+'.' );`

```js
let error = {
  name: ["This field is required", "Another error"],
  age: ["Only numeric characters are allowed"]
};


Object.entries(error).map(x=>error[x[0]]=x[1].join('. ')+'.');
console.log(error);
```

In this way you can wrap it in function (immutable):

```
let var func = (e,r={})=>(Object.entries(e).map(x=>r[x[0]]=x[1].join('. ')+'.'),r);
let result = func(error) // run it in this way
```

Comment: If you want to give minus point leave also comment with explanation

Comment: I tried running the test on bottom and got “  TypeError: x[1].join is not a function”. The test I am trying to pass is on the bottom

Comment: @Saul I update answer (add extra dot at last array element) - may be now this function pass your test.

Comment: Still even with the updated code  returning "TypeError: x[1].join is not a function"

Comment: @Saul you change question, it's more complicated now and I don't have time to implement new solution - however wait for answers of other people and click on gray 'check' button (on their answer left side) if they solution will helps you.

Comment: Hey I updated the code to where the outcome is immutable, I tested your code but .join still throws in error do to it being immutable

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
error.reduce((prev,next,key) => prev.concat(`${key}: "${next.join('. ')}". `),'')
```